# WAR Data hazard in MIPS-like pipeline architecture

Tags: architecture, mips, pipeline

Say we have the following set of instructions:

1:    lw $f6, 20($gp)

2:    lw $f2, 28($gp)

3:    mult $f0, $f2, $f4

4:    sw $f3, 32($gp)

I can see possibility of there being a WAR hazard between instructions 1 and 4 (likewise for 2 and 4), but am unsure.

Basically we **read** from $gp+20 and write into $f6, then read from $f3 and **write** into $gp+32. Surely if both instances were dealing with $gp+20, there would be a WAR data hazard, but because the addresses ultimately being affected are different ($gp+20 vs. $gp+32), I'm unsure if there could still be a hazard. My reason for believing there may be is because both instructions are still trying to access $gp, and only after reaching for $gp is whatever constant added to reach the updated address. Would this be correct?

Thanks

Comment: Also, you're mixing floating point register names with integer opcodes, so that code will not build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My reason for believing there may be is because both instructions are still trying to access $gp, and only after reaching for $gp is whatever constant added to reach the updated address. Would this be correct?

No, as `$gp` is not changing in this code sequence.

---

These hazards occur within the processor, and they have to do with the order the processor executes the microarchitectural operations of register read and register write.  Since the pipeline spreads instructions out over several cycles (used by the pipeline stages), the read of a register and the write of a register (for a different instruction) can occur in some kind of overlapping manner.

These hazards do not concern themselves with memory reads and writes — just register reads and writes.

A `lw $s6, 20($gp)` has one register read, `$gp` and one register write, `$s6`.

A `sw $f3, 32($gp)` has two register reads, `$gp`, and `$f3`, and no register writes.

WAR — Write After Read — requires a register write for the latter instruction and a register read for the former.  Instructions 1&4 do not meet the pattern because instruction 4 has no register writes (yes, it writes to memory and that has its own ordering issues, but the W in WAR refers to a register write, which `sw` doesn't do).

Comment: I would have thought a sw is one register read and one register write (eg. sw $f3, 32($gp) is reading $f3, writing it to 32($gp)?) I thank you for the great explanation in the rest of the post.

Comment: Both registers are read.  What do you think `sw` does?  The only thing written to is memory, which is not a register.  `$gp` provides a value used to compute the memory address.